# how to create shortcodes for custom fields?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, custom-fields

I was wondering how to create shortcodes for custom fields?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYS5U.png)

Comment: did you try any plugin? something like this  https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fields-shortcodes/

Comment: @Dipak Shortcodes allow you to recall a set of information, it is commonly used in wordpress to save you time on content writing or development.

I am trying to see how I can make shortcodes read from Custom fields, and to use those shortcodes to retrieve information without the need to write them again and again everytime I want to add commonly used information in a page

Comment: :D then my bad, I guess my question wasn't clear. I am not a developer, that's why I need your help with the code part.

Comment: @Dipak I have a set of course pages, here is few examples: https://ihna.edu.au/lp/school-education/certificate-iii-early-childhood-education-care and this one https://www.ihna.edu.au/lp/school-community-services/certificate-iii-individual-support

I have other 6 of them, I want to utilise the custom field section in wordpress, add some critical information like "Course Duration" and "Course Fees" for example and turn them into shortcodes to use in my template so I don't write them down everytime I create a page. Your guidance please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple shortcode creating example

```
function customfield_function() {
  return 'i am describing my custom fields name here bla bla';
}
add_shortcode('customfield', 'customfield_function');

[customfield]
```

For more [click](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) here

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that plugin, I will try the code as well.